# Add comma after all words containing a digit in bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, replace, google-bigquery, concatenation

In **bigquery** I would like to add a comma after ALL words in a string IF AND ONLY IF the word contains one or more digits AND the word is not currently followed immediately by a comma.

**The main problems:** 1) performing a match against all examples in the string rather than just the first. 2) inserting the comma.

**Sample statement:** SELECT ____________ FROM UNNEST(["5 the ridings", "the ridings 5", "t5he ridings", "5-6 the ridings", "flat 5 the ridings", "flat5 the ridings", "26 and 32a the ridings", "101-103 the ridings", "101 - 103 the ridings", "52b, and a53a the ridings", "flat 8,42 the ridings", "a55 the ridings", "5a the ridings", "the ridings", "52b, the ridings"]) t

**Conditions:**

"5 the ridings" -->  5, the ridings
"the ridings 5" --> the ridings 5,
"t5he ridings" --> t5he, ridings
"5-6 the ridings" --> 5-6, the ridings
"flat 5 the ridings" --> flat 5, the ridings
"flat5 the ridings" --> flat5, the ridings
"26 and 32a the ridings" --> 26, and 32a, the ridings
"101-103 the ridings" --> 101-103, the ridings
"101 - 103 the ridings" --> 101, - 103, the ridings
"52b, and a53a the ridings" --> 52b, and a53a, the ridings
"flat 8,42 the ridings" --> flat 8,42, the ridings
"a55 the ridings" --> a55, the ridings
"5a the ridings" --> 5a, the ridings
"the ridings" == the ridings
"52b, the ridings" == 52b, the ridings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regular expression problem.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT u,
       regexp_replace(u, r'([^ ]*[0-9]+[^ ,]*)([ ]|$)', r'\1,\2')
FROM UNNEST(["t5he ridings", "the ridings 5", "5-6 the ridings", "flat 5 the ridings", "flat5 the ridings", "26 and 32a the ridings", "101-103 the ridings", "101 - 103 the ridings", "101 - 103 the ridings", "52b, and a53a the ridings", "flat 8,42 the ridings", "a55 the ridings", "5a the ridings", "the ridings", "52b, the ridings"]) u
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close but interestingly failed on the condition:
52b, and a53a the ridings --> 52b, and a53a, the ridings. It instead produced 52b,, and a53a, the ridings

Comment: @JonathanFrancis . . . The built-in patterns such as `\W` for word ending characters don't do exactly what you want.